# In Java, list of different classes?

Tags: java, list

I've got abstract class Subject, then classes Subject1, Subject2 etc. which extend Subject.

Instead of writing if subject==1 then, else if subject==2 then etc

I want to use some kind of list, where on entering an index, would return me a subject

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to create new objects on demand, or select from existing ones?

If the last, use a `List<Subject>` like Joshc1107 proposed.

If the first, you in fact want a factory:

```
public interface SubjectFactory {
    public Subject create(int type);
}
```

... or maybe a list of such factories (then you don't need the type):

```
interface SubjectFactory {
    public Subject create();
}

List<SubjectFactory> factories = Arrays.asList(
      null, // we don't have type 0
      new SubjectFactory() { public Subject create() {
           return new Subject1();
      }},
      new SubjectFactory() { public Subject create() {
           return new Subject2();
      }},
      new SubjectFactory() { public Subject create() {
           return new Subject3();
      }},
      new SubjectFactory() { public Subject create() {
           return new Subject4();
      }});

public Subject create(int type) {
    return factories.get(type).create();
}
```

Comment: This is a good implementation, but I would rather use an enum as the look up instead of an integer. As implemented calling `create(-1)` and `create(1000)` cause exceptions, but will not be prevented at compile time.

Comment: Existing ones, s1 = new Subject1(); s2 = new Subject2(); subjects = new ArrayList(); subjecs.add(s1); subjects.add(s2); public int getCurrentSubject(){ int i=0; while(i<subjects.size()){ if (subjects.get(i).getStudents()){ return i; } } } – sasha 56 mins ago 
 
just did a bit more debugging subjects.get(i).getStudents() returns class Object not class SubjectX

Comment: @unholysampler: I thought about adding such a remark, but I'm not sure where the number comes from. If it is read from external sources, an enum complicates it only.

Comment: @shasha: Please add additions to your question like this to the question (there is an edit button), not as comments, it is better readable and easier found. (I think you should use generic types here.)

Comment: @sasha: That is because you used the non-parametrized `ArrayList`. You need `List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>()` and it will return a `Subject`.

Answer (score 0):

that s called  a map , table, hashtable, dictionary, assocative array.

Comment: while an index based collection could be a map, table...., usually it' s just a list.

Comment: just did a bit more debugging subjects.get(i).getStudents() returns class Object not class SubjectX

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ArrayList<Subject>`, as defined [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  It's one I personally go to often, and it allows you to get items by index using the `get(int index)` command.

Comment: can I use it for different classes? so that I can say ArrayList<Subject> subjects; subjects.add(s1= new Subject1); subjects.get(i).getStudents();  - because that's what I'm doing right now, and I'm getting compilation error - getStudents() method not found

Comment: yes, subjects.get(i) would return a Subject object.  So if you have a getStudents() method defined in your Subject class that call would work.  However, it seems as if you've not defined a getStudents() method in your Students class.

Comment: but I have separate class Subject1, class Subject2 and class Subject3, would it return SubjectX object?

Comment: Aaah, I see.  What you'll need to do if you want to implement specific functions, create a parent class with a getStudents() method.  Then override that method in child implementations as you need for each individual subject class.

Comment: I personally prefer using HashMap<Integer,Subject>.

Comment: Sorry, just clarifying what I need to do, I have Abstract class SchoolSubject, with abstract method enrolStudents(); and concrete method getStudents(); - do I implement getStudents() in all Subject1, Subject2 and Subject3, or just in SchoolSubject?

Comment: either.  If the getStudents() implementation is the same for all child classes, you can go ahead and implement it in the SchoolSubject class (and each child will automatically inherit it).  However, if each child implements this differently, you will need to define getStudents() in each child class.  You may also do a mixture by defining a default implementation in SchoolSubject and overriding the default implementation only when necessary.

Comment: I just tried it, and I get compilation error -can't find symbol- method getStudents() - I used subjects.get(i).getStudents()) what else could have gone wrong? sorry for bugging you with my code so much

Comment: s1 = new Subject1();
s2 = new Subject2();
subjects = new ArrayList();
subjecs.add(s1);
subjects.add(s2);


public int getCurrentSubject(){
int i=0;
while(i<subjects.size()){
if (subjects.get(i).getStudents()){
return i;
}
}
}

Comment: just did a bit more debugging subjects.get(i).getStudents() returns class Object not class SubjectX